# Is there a function in spark df that can be replaced by applymap?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Below is the code written for pandas df, because of memory issue i had to move to PySpark which is why i need to convert this code so that it can be executed for spark df. I tried running this directly but it generates an error.What can be the alternative for the code below in PySpark?

```
def units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1

sets = df.applymap(units)
```

Here, is the error i'm getting:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7e54b4e7a7e7> in <module>()
----> 1 sets = pivoted.applymap(units)

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1180         if name not in self.columns:
   1181             raise AttributeError(
-> 1182                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
   1183         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
   1184         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'applymap'
```

Comment: Pyspark dataframe doesnot have applymap attribute, tale a look at when+otherwise: `df.select(*[F.when(F.col(i)<=0,0).otherwise(1).alias(i) for i in df.columns]).show()` ? after you have imported the sql functions as `F ` like `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your units function as a UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

def units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1

units_udf = udf(lambda x: units(x), LongType())

df = spark.createDataFrame([(-1,), (0,), (1,), (2,)], ['id'])

df.show()
+---+                                                                           
| id|
+---+
| -1|
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
+---+

sets = df.withColumn("id", units_udf(col("id")))
sets.show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  0|
|  1|
|  1|
+---+
```

Comment: what if i want to apply the udf to all columns i.e. entire dataframe?

Comment: There are two ways I can think of. You can convert all columns of your dataframe to a single column of a complex type (struct), and pass that column to a UDF. Or you can convert your dataframe to an rdd of Rows, call a map on that rdd (your function inside map will have to accept and return Row type), and then convert back to dataframe.